# Sending text results to the clipboard in Xcode

Tags: pasteboard

This is within the latest Xcode.

I have 4 arrays that produce a result to the screen with an OK button. I would like to add a function that copies the result to the clipboard. Does that make sense?

While I am not exactly sure how this is done, I am heavily researching it as I am somewhat new to coding.

From what I am seeing, pasteboards would seem to be the way to go.
Am I in the right ball field here?

Here is a sampling of my code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
NSInteger firstRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kfirstComponent];
NSInteger middleRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kmiddleComponent];
NSInteger lastRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:klastComponent];
NSInteger fourthRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kfourthComponent];
NSString *first = [firstTypes objectAtIndex:firstRow];
NSString *middle = [middleTypes objectAtIndex:middleRow];
NSString *last = [lastTypes objectAtIndex:lastRow];
NSString *fourth = [fourthTypes objectAtIndex:fourthRow];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@.",first, middle, last, fourth]; 
UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text"
    message:message
            delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
}
```

This is the code (I think) i want to Implement:

```
-(IBAction)copy:(id)sender
{
NSString *copyString = label.text;
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:copyString];
}
```

And if I have the correct usage, I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: You might want to clarify the platform (OS X?) and APIs you're trying to target. It's a completely different concept to manipulate the clipboard for every single major OS.

Comment: And... You are correct. I wrongly assumed that this was strictly Xcode. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:message];
```

below the line of code that delivers the result.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9473750/4) to the question [Sending text results to the clipboard in Xcode (Found the solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473750/sending-text-results-to-the-clipboard-in-xcode-found-the-solution) by the OP [Phineas T Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236146/phineas-t-parks) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>